# How can i change Android Default Home screen Code and Replace my Customize Home Screen application source code?

Tags: android, customization, firmware

Here i already make one customize home screen launcher application for android.
Now i want to add this application in Android Source code.
And Remove Default android home screen source code from Android 2.3 source code. than i want to built whole Android Source code after replacing default home screen source code on `EVOLUTION MODULE`.

I want to know Steps About this how can i achieve this.

So please Share your idea how can i replace default home screen source code to my home screen source code.

i already download the source code of android 2.3. but i have no idea where i have to change in code. which files i have to replace.? i want changes in framework level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't include the standard launcher .apk in your device, but do include your own.  You don't need to configure anything, just include the launcher app you want in your final system image.