# Modify android home screen

Tags: android, homescreen

I am creating an android that acts as a media center. I would like to modify the android home screen. What I want is a customized home screen displaying only my application on booting and never display  the default android menu  other menu buttons or menu drawer that android has. is it possible.

I got a few links: 
 [How can I create a custom home-screen replacement application for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android)

But is it possible to get what i want please help

Comment: Are you creating an Android device or an Android app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to create an android app to make the phone run in sort of a kiosk mode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881373/is-it-possible-to-create-an-android-app-to-make-the-phone-run-in-sort-of-a-kiosk) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146903/how-can-i-change-android-default-home-screen-code-and-replace-my-customize-home

Comment: slayton I am creating an android device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely create a home screen replacement. To do that, your app must have an activity with android.intent.category.HOME in its filters (in AndroidManifest.xml). That's how the system knows which application will display the home screen... For more info:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html

(Search for android.intent.category.HOME to go straight to the point)

Comment: I i give the above option will it exit from the app if i press back or exit button. I dont want it to exit from my app.